# How to add multiple HTML pages to code snippets on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-snippets

How do you add multiple HTML pages to code snippets on Stack Overflow? If your code is interlinked with multiple HTML pages, then how do you add multiple pages in code snippets on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not all sites have code snippets. Perhaps this is better asked on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Catija: PP&CG and CR would probably appreciate it staying on MSE.